# SharePoint Help Desk

Tags: workflow, email, incoming-email

We are trying to implement a request center/help desk using an announcements list (`reason, it will allow incoming emails`).

When a user sends an email to the mailbox, a new ticket is created, included in the subject line and sent as as alert to the user.

Now, the issue is, if the user replies to that email with comments and/or more details, it should not create a new list item (`set a condition not to create a new ticket`), but should copy the message body to the existing ticket.

Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

We developed ready to use SharePoint help desk with support of incoming email messages. It is quite customizable. I would recommend you to take a look.

I'm not sure which version of SharePoint do you use, but it supports SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online in office 365.

- [Product page](https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-helpdesk/)
- [Docs](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/index.html)
- [Series of articles for quick start](https://plumsail.com/blog/category/helpdesk/)